# Determine location of Bitmap from Matrix

Tags: android, matrix, graphics, bitmap

I would like to find the x-y coordinates of a bitmap image that was drawn directly to a canvas in a fragment. Unfortunately the class that handles the drawing only exposes the transformation matrix, so I have been trying to extract the information from that.

As I understand it, the first two rows of the last column should be the x-y coordinates should it not? That doesn't seem to be the case for me. I tried

```
float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
float x = matrixValues[2];
float y = matrixValues[5];
```

But those coordinates are off the screen. Any advice?

Comment: It depends on code which works with matrix. I suppose there is only one advice: look into the source code.

Comment: In the source code they only use the provided postTranslate postRotate and postScale methods and pass the matrix to the canvas...nothing else. Why  would the structure of the matrix change depending on what they do with it?